# How to combine this two "if" conditions?

Tags: php, if-statement

With this code I get the last 3 posts that contain "solar-signs-related" tag on the custom post "product" page that have "solar-signs-streetscape-elements" term.

But how to combine two "if" so it will display also the blog posts that have "interior-system-related" tag if the custom post "products" page is "interior-systems"?

```
if ( has_term( 'interior-systems', 'categories' ) ) {
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'showposts' => 3,
  'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('interior-systems-related') )
    )
);
}
if ( has_term( 'solar-signs-streetscape-elements', 'categories' ) ) {
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'showposts' => 3,
  'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
      'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => array('solar-signs-related') )
   )
 );
 }
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) :       
$query->the_post(); ?>           
<div class="post-wrap relat relatblog">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>                   
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
  endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'showposts' => 3,
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('interior-systems-related') )
            )
        );

if ( has_term( 'interior-systems', 'categories' ) ) {
    $args['tax_query']['terms'] = array('interior-systems-related');
} else if ( has_term( 'solar-signs-streetscape-elements', 'categories' ) ) {
    $args['tax_query']['terms'] = array('solar-signs-related');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array terms, that hold needed categories and than form args with them:

```
  <?php
  $terms = array();
  if ( has_term( 'interior-systems', 'categories' ) ) {
    $terms[] = 'interior-systems';

  }
  if ( has_term( 'solar-signs-streetscape-elements', 'categories' ) ) {
    $terms[] = 'solar-signs-streetscape-elements';
  }
  if (!empty($terms)) {
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'post',
      'showposts' => 3,
      'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
      'post_status' => array('publish'),
      'orderby' => 'date',
      'order' => 'DESC',
        'tax_query' => array(
         array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field' => 'slug',
          'terms' => $terms )
       )
     );
    );
  }
  $query = new WP_Query($args);

  if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) :       
  $query->the_post(); ?>           
  <div class="post-wrap relat relatblog">
  <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
  </div>                   
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;
    endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if ( has_term( array('interior-systems', 'solar-signs-streetscape-elements'), 'categories' ) ) {
  $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'showposts' => 3,
  'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
  'post_status' => array('publish'),
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
     array(
    'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => array('interior-systems-related', 'solar-signs-related') )
    )
);
}

$query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) :       
$query->the_post(); ?>           
<div class="post-wrap relat relatblog">
<h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
</div>                   
  <?php endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  endif;
  endwhile; ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query